# Using ms-excel to search and reduce particular repeated values to single value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have excel document which has **IP address** as

**SourceIp**

```
192.168.2.4
............
............
............
............
192.168.2.44

192.168.55.4
............
............
............
............
192.168.55.12
```

So, I want to search where first three **octets match** e.g 192.168.55 based upon this criteria I want to match where all first three octets match and put the result of matched filter in seperate rows / columns. The result would be for (reducing multiple repeated entries) to single value e.g 192.168.55.

I'm using ms-excel 2003. Can this be done? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a column with the following formula filled down (where `A1` is the first IP address):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("!!!",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","!!!",3))-1)
```

This will return the IP address up to the third period.

You can then use the Advanced Filter (on the Data Ribbon) to filter for unique records in this new column. Have the filter print the result wherever you want the list to go.